# MDX calculated dimension attribute

Tags: ssas, mdx

Is it possible to create a query scoped dimension attribute (as is done with measures) using the `WITH` statement.

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
WITH
MEMBER [Customer].[Has Child At Home] AS
IIF( [Customer].[Number of Cars Owned] > 0,
True,
False
```

)

And then use the above attribute in a select statement however it is giving me an error saying that the customer dimension has more than one hierarchy and that one needs to be specified.

Answer (score 0):

In this format it requires a hierarchy, to build on your code example `[Number of Cars Owned]` would need to be a hierarchy:

```
WITH
  MEMBER [Customer].[Number of Cars Owned].[Has Child At Home] AS
  IIF([Customer].[Number of Cars Owned] > 0, "True", "False")
SELECT
  {[Customer].[Has Child at Home]} ON COLUMNS,
  [DimExample].[AttributeExample].Members ON ROWS,
FROM [CubeExample]
```

See [Creating Query-Scoped Calculated Members (MDX)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms146017.aspx)